# Ciclo for dentro de un return

Tags: javascript

En una función estoy armando un arreglo con n posiciones, en este ejemplo tiene 4 posiciones, en el momento del return necesito que se ejecute un cilo for, por la lógica del algoritmo original no se puede ejecutar el ciclo for dentro de la función, he simplificado a su máxima expresión el código, solo para repetir el error.

**Este es mi código:**

```
function triple () {

    arr = [1,2,3,4];

    return for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] * 3;

    };
};


triple();
```

**Este es el error que me genera:**

```
 $ node script.js
/home/javascript/pruebas/script.js:6
    return for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
 $
```

**NOTA:** *No se si esto es factible, por eso pregunto y si es factible como quedaría el código.*

Comment: "por la lógica del algoritmo original no se puede ejecutar el ciclo for dentro de la función" Podrías elaborar?

Comment: Esa sintaxis no parece válida, recomiendo leas https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/return

Comment: El comando for no devuelve ningún valor, por lo que no tienen sentido colocarlo como parámetro de un return.
Dicho de otra manera, la sintaxis es incorrecta.

Comment: Gracias, cada día aprendo un poquito más de js, voy a meditar tu comentario para internalizarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pensando en la usabilidad de tu función, es buena idea recibir como parámetro el arreglo que deseas multiplicar.

También puedes usar la función `Array.prototype.map()` para ejecutar operaciones para cada elemento del Array

```js
function triple (arr) {
    return arr.map(function(num) {
        return num*3;
    });
};

var arreglo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
resultado = triple(arreglo);
console.warn(arreglo); // [1, 2, 3, 4] (El arreglo original queda intacto)
console.warn(resultado); // [3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Un return debe ser una expresión que pueda evaluarse  a un valor. En tu caso debes primero multiplicar los elementos del arreglo y luego retornar el arreglo:

```
function triple () {

    arr = [1,2,3,4];

     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // multiplicar elementos del arreglo
        arr[i] *= 3;

    };
  // retornar el arreglo
  return arr;
};
```